# ImageResizer - Getting generic error GDI while resizing image

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

Here is my Image resizing code.

```
private void ResizeImage(int width, int height, string szFilePath, string destinationPath)
        {
            //var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            //watch.Start();

            Serilog.Log.ForContext<ImageResizeHandler>().Information($"Image resize process start for file :{szFilePath}");
            var instructions = getInstructions(width, height);
            try
            {               
                ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(szFilePath, szFilePath, instructions);

                File.Move(szFilePath, destinationPath);

                //watch.Stop();
                Serilog.Log.ForContext<ImageResizeHandler>().Information($"Image resize process end for file :{szFilePath}");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Serilog.Log.ForContext<ImageResizeHandler>().Error(ex, $"Failed to Resize the Image - filePath: {szFilePath}");

                // If memory leak exception or any other error then use default thumbnail image.
                File.Copy(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/placeholder_160x180.png"), destinationPath);
            }
        }
```

While resizing image, I am getting following error

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageFormat format)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder.SavePng(Image img, Stream target)
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder.Write(Image image, Stream s)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.BuildJobBitmapToStream(ImageJob job, Bitmap source, Stream dest)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.BuildJob(ImageJob job)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.BuildInternal(ImageJob job)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.BuildInQueue(ImageJob job, Boolean useSemaphore, Int32 maxQueuingMilliseconds, CancellationToken cancel)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(ImageJob job)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, Instructions instructions)
   at CampaignerImageResizer.ImageResizeHandler.ResizeImage(Int32 width, Int32 height, String szFilePath, String destinationPath) in C:\agent\_work\49\s\CampaignerImageResizer\ImageResizeHandler.ashx.cs:line 56
```

getting exception "A generic error occurred in GDI+." on line ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(szFilePath, szFilePath, instructions);

I am using this library https://imageresizing.net/

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you're writing to the same file you're reading from. Write to destinationPath instead and the issue shojl

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/166893/lilith-river

Thanks for quick reply. 
But my issue is intermittent. 
sometime it is working and sometime it giving exception. 
Also locally it's working fine, but on deployment it is not working all the time.
Is this really issue like source & destination path is same ? 

Thanks!

Comment: File locking is an intermittent sort of thing. And the error message is external to GDI, and occurs during writing to disk, so there's not much else to suspect.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine, but it is missing the implementation of the `getInstructions()` method used to retrieve the resizing instructions for the `ImageBuilder object.`

To fix this error, you need to implement the `getInstructions()` method to return the correct instructions for resizing the image to the desired dimensions.